# Converting object file to LLVM bitcode

Tags: binary-analysis

Frameworks like [mcsema](https://github.com/trailofbits/mcsema) is used to convert an executable file into LLVM bitcode which can be further used to perform program analysis.

Is there any way to convert an object file in the similar way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly, there are at least two ways I can think of:

- Add support for object file parsing to McSema
- Link the object file into a dummy executable and parse that.

You could also write your own lifter to llvm IR that works on object files :)